# How to look for a specific folder with require in node js

Tags: node.js

[image]I need to require() method to load modules from a folder nonother that node_modules folder. Is there a way to do that without using any npm libraries.

EX- There is an **age** folder inside the **modules** folder with an index.js file. I need to import that module like

```
const age = require('age')
```

without giving the relative path of the module.

Comment: Please show us the EXACT folder structure you're trying to load from.  Otherwise see the doc https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders for the other places node.js will load from without a path.

Comment: My answer would to not create this problem for yourself in the first place.  Either place the modules in an expected `node_modules` location, in an expected global location or use a path to indicate where to load it from.

Comment: Your answer for how `require()` works is all in that doc reference I gave you. If you want just `require('age')` to find it, I think you will have to put its path in `NODE_PATH` or replace/hook `require()` to give it new behaviors. Based on the doc, I don't see any other way. I would argue that you're doing something wrong in your design when you have this problem. This is not how node.js was built to run and you're trying to sub-vert it somehow.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to do that without using any npm libraries.

The answer to that sort of thing is always "yes" because those libraries are written in JavaScript.

I would warmly recommend against it and for standard approaches (like using yarn workspaces and declaring `age` as a proper local npm module) but you can always do something like a require hook:

```js
const originalRequire = Module.prototype.require;
Module.prototype.require = function moduleRequire(id) {
  if(id === 'age') {
    return require('./modules/age');
  }
  return originalRequire.call(this, id);
}
```

Or add your local `modules` folder to the `NODE_PATH` environment variable so it finds it there.

**Neither of these are good options and I recommend against both of them**.

It is better to stick to the standard modus operandi and vendor and consume "proper" npm modules.